# REST API along with startswith and tolower function method in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, javascript, sharepoint-server, office-365, rest

I would like to bind all users into textbox autocomplete event. I done with below script but it is consider `case sensitive expression` while searching the results.

```
  $("#txtselectuser").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: appwebUrl + "/_api/web/SiteUsers?$filter=startswith(Title,'" + request.term + "')",
            method: "GET",
            async: true,
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var results = data.d.results;
                response($.map(results, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.Title,
                        val: item.Id
                    }
                }))
            },
            error: function (data) {
            }
        });
    },
    select: function (e, i) {
        $("#txtselectuser").val(i.item.label);
        $("input#elm_inputuserid").val(i.item.val);

    },
    minLength: 1
});
```

> It will returns results based on Display Title of all users. 
>   For Example : We have couple of users `1) Jignesh Rajput 2) Jigs`

When I searched on Textbox with `Jig` - it will return both of users but I have type on textbox with `jig`(all lowercase characters) it will return `0 results`.

[Here](http://platinumdogs.me/2013/03/14/sharepoint-adventures-with-the-rest-api-part-1/) is link for showing all filter expression for REST API.

I want - will not carry case-sensitive characters and return all matches results.

I tried with `tolower` functional expression however it is not working.. like :

```
 ?$filter=startswith(tolower(Title),'jig')",
```

Comment: How many users do you expect? Workaround might be to get all of the users from the list, load the into a JS object with a calculated lower-cased title property, then request further info for them later by their ID -- this only works for a limited number of users though naturally

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [OData query operators supported in the SharePoint REST service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385(v=office.15).aspx#bk_supported) `tolower` operator is not supported.

**Solution 1**

Use `listdata.svc` REST endpoint instead.

In your case, the request for finding `User` by `Display Name` could be converted into this one:

```
/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/UserInformationList?$filter=startswith(Name,'<Name>')
```

Key Points:

- `User Information List` is used for query the User
- `tolower` operator is omitted since the specified request is
  *case-insensitive*

**Solution 2**

The idea is to apply some kind of verification for the value passed into `filter` query option, for example:

```
function capitalize(name)
{
    return name[0].toUpperCase() + name.slice(1);
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7224605/1375553)

```
var endpointUri = appwebUrl + "/_api/web/SiteUsers?$filter=startswith(Title,'" + capitalize(request.term) + "')";
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, tolower is not supported by the SharePoint 2013 REST API

[image: screenshot from MSDN documentation]

From the [SharePoint 2013 REST Service article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385(v=office.15).aspx#bk_supported)

This is one of those areas where SharePoint still differs from the standard web-world implementation :)